# Server Certificate does NOT include an ID -- Bitnami Google Computer Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, certificate, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I am attempting to test a Rails sample app deployment on Google Compute Engine with Bitnami. At present I have configured all files and run the server successfully. In attempting to access the Rails app, the following error appears in the logs

```
AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

I have seen that this certificate provided with Bitnami deployment is for the domain http://www.example.com, how can I create and configure for that it will point to my domain?

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

Those are dummy certificates that serve as an example. You'll have to create one and sign it yourself. After you get one, you can follow this documentation page in order to set apache to use yours:

https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache#How_to_enable_HTTPS_support_with_SSL_certificates